# At what pressure will ice remain as ice at 1000° C?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I am in 9th grade. Please forgive me if I ask any dumb questions. So, I was studying about gas laws and I came across an equation

$$\frac{p_1V_1}{T_1} = \frac{p_2V_2}{T_2}.$$

I wondered if there is such an equation for solids and if there is what should be the pressure so that ice remains as ice at 1000° C?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics StackExchange. There is no such thing as a dumb question. Could you please clarify in which context you encountered the equation your question is about. This would be very helpful to provide an answer for your question.

Comment: Water ice cannot be kept in its solid form via pressure. Due to its anomalous density dependence, it will liquify under pressure, both from solid (ice skating) and gaseous (pressure cooker) phases. Though there might be some more exotic solid ultra-high pressure phases with even higher density than liquid water

Comment: Look a this picture of water 's phase diagram https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Phase_diagram_of_water.svg it shows phases up to 350C and it is ice VII above 200kbar and the curve between liquid and ice VII is nearly linear between 70C and 350C, so it may still go up to 1000C but I cannot find data for that.

Comment: Ice VII isnt stable above a few 100 °C. more extensive phase diagram here: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Phase-diagram-of-H2O-Pressure-temperature-conditions-of-the-XRD-measurements-in-the_fig4_332961479

Comment: have you asked your teacher?

Comment: @tobalt Please convert your answers-in-comments to answers (or a unified answer). Your phase diagram link is useful, your ice-skating explanation a [misconception](https://www.vox.com/platform/amp/science-and-health/2018/2/13/16973886/why-is-ice-slippery).

Comment: @tobalt thank you for your explanation

Comment: Also thank you all for your help/answers

Comment: @jan0155 I came across this equation while I was studying about Charle's law and Boyle's law